# Dropbox api , use oauth 2 with the sdk

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I am trying to get the oauth2 token using the ios SDK. Currently the ios SDK returns me 2 tokens using oauth1, is there a way for it to use oauth2 instead?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here which mentions that it is not using oauth2 yet: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=103057#post-556973